# Laravel 5 IoC type-hinting not working

Tags: php, laravel, inversion-of-control, laravel-5

As far as I've understood, I should be able to type-hint my class instance arguments in the constructor of my class that I only instantiate with help of a Service Provider. Unfortunately I'm getting an error about missing arguments.

Tracker.php

```
function __construct($query, Tracker\Shipment $shipment) {
    $this->query    = $query;
    $this->shipment = $shipment;
}
```

TrackerServiceProvider.php

```
class TrackerServiceProvider extends \Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider {
    public function register() {
        $this->app->bind('TrackerAPI',  function($app, $shipment_number) {
            return new Tracker\API($shipment_number); // omitting Shipment argument should resolve on its own?
        });
    }
}
```

Class API is extending Tracker, thus using its constructor. Why isn't it resolving without the implied class type hint?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've confused the PHP `new` functionality with Laravel's dependency injection via type hinting functionality.

In your `TrackerAPI` binding, when you specify `return new Tracker\API($shipment_number);`, there is nothing built into PHP to try to flesh out any missing parameters. To do this, you would need to `return $app->make('Tracker\API', [$shipment_number]);`

When you use the `App::make()` method, Laravel will do its magic to create a new object. It first checks for an explicitly defined binding. If it doesn't find an explicit binding, it will fall back to just using a combination of the supplied parameters plus type hints to create objects for any missing parameters.

Take the following statement: `App::make('Tracker\API', [$shipment_number])`. Assume there is no explicitly defined binding for `Tracker\API`. The `Tracker\API` constructor requires two parameters. `$shipment_number` is passed in in the parameter array, so it will be used as the first parameter. Since only one parameter was supplied, Laravel will `App::make()` the rest of the parameters using the type hints.

However, when you specifically instantiate the object yourself using the `new` keyword, none of this happens. It is a plain PHP object instantiation.

Comment: So what you're saying is if I abandon my bindings (service providers) and use `App::make(Tracker\API)` right away in my controller, it will work as I first thought?

Comment: @silkfire Yes, as long as you pass in the parameters that can't be built via type hints (such as your `$shipment_number`). You only need to define your bindings if you're trying to do something that Laravel can't figure out on its own. For example, if you're injecting an Interface, you need to create a binding to tell Laravel what instance to build for that interface.  Or, if you don't want to inject a `new` instance, but an existing one (such as if you were injecting the [Sentry](https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry/2.1) service).

Comment: thank you so much! I just used the make method, provided the shipping number in an array and it auto resolved itself magically. I actually don't need no service provider then! Which in one way is good but now I'm getting even more confused on when I ever would need them. I've never have had to make sure to use the same instance of a class, then I simply just reuse the already created variable in my code...

Answer (score 2):

Nope. Laravel can't resolve partials like that. You have to be explicit:

```php
use Tracker\API;
use Tracker\Shipment;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class TrackerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('TrackerAPI',  function($app, $shipment_number)
        {
            return new API($shipment_number, $app[Shipment::class]);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But why have I misunderstood the concept of type hinting and auto-resolution then? Or does it only work for interfaces and not classes?

Comment: The query argument isn't type hinted. Laravel doesn't know what to pass on construction. The service provider explicitly stated what should be passed every time the object is instantiated.